# Can't save a keras model after training my model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm following a code example from keras.io about *A Vision Transformer without Attention*, [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/shiftvit/). I want to save it in the `tensorflow/keras` after completing training but it generates an error. The last part of my model code is given below

```
# Get the total number of steps for training.
total_steps = int((len(x_train) / config.batch_size) * config.epochs)

# Calculate the number of steps for warmup.
warmup_epoch_percentage = 0.15
warmup_steps = int(total_steps * warmup_epoch_percentage)

# Initialize the warmupcosine schedule.
scheduled_lrs = WarmUpCosine(
lr_start=1e-5, lr_max=1e-3, warmup_steps=warmup_steps, total_steps=total_steps,
)

# Get the optimizer.
optimizer = tfa.optimizers.AdamW(
learning_rate=scheduled_lrs, weight_decay=config.weight_decay
)

# Compile and pretrain the model.
model.compile(
optimizer=optimizer,
loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
metrics=[
    keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name="accuracy"),
    keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(5, name="top-5-accuracy"),
],
)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
train_ds,
epochs=config.epochs,
validation_data=val_ds,
callbacks=[
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_accuracy", patience=5, mode="auto",)
],
)

# Evaluate the model with the test dataset.
print("TESTING")
loss, acc_top1, acc_top5 = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print(f"Loss: {loss:0.2f}")
print(f"Top 1 test accuracy: {acc_top1*100:0.2f}%")
print(f"Top 5 test accuracy: {acc_top5*100:0.2f}%")
```

I tried below two methods to save my model

```
model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/VIT-SHIFT')
```

and

```
history.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/VIT-SHIFT')
```

but it says model and history are not defined. Full code is available in [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/106GsgIh4bXwQKDT0jtjsvvYzUcr0BOg4?usp=sharing%5D)

Comment: This is hard to debug for us because we do not see the relationship in code between all three blocks, specially if you use something like ipython/jupyter, maybe you did not run the cells in the right order or not run some cells.

Comment: Can you provide the full code?

Comment: Full code is available here [HERE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/106GsgIh4bXwQKDT0jtjsvvYzUcr0BOg4?usp=sharing)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your other question about the same code, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72484085/9215780), you may need to implement the `call` method first. Now, saving and reloading the model should be straightforward but I've encountered an issue regarding a `layers.RandomCrop` augmentation layer that is used in the code.

```
def get_augmentation_model():
    """Build the data augmentation model."""
    data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Resizing(..),
            layers.RandomCrop(...), # <--- possible causes
            layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
            layers.Rescaling(1 / 255.0),
        ]
    )
    return data_augmentation
```

> Called a function referencing variables that have been deleted. This likely means that function-local variables were created and not referenced elsewhere in the program. This is generally a mistake; consider storing variables in an object attribute on the first call.

Though I looked over the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py#L444-L530) but didn't feel any suspicious bug. So, to end this, I've implemented custom random crop layers which theoretically do the same. However, if you insist to use built-in `layers.RandomCrop`, then I would recommend opening a ticket on GitHub regarding this issue.

---

To make the whole code end-to-end training and saving+reloading, change the code as follows. First, implement the `call` method in the `ShiftViTModel` class.

```
class ShiftViTModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
        # init params

    def get_config(self):
        ...
        return config

    def _calculate_loss(self, data, training=False):
        ...
        return total_loss, labels, logits

    def train_step(self, inputs):
        ...
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

    def test_step(self, data):
        ...
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
    
    # implement the call function
    def call(self, images):
        augmented_images = self.data_augmentation(images)
        x = self.patch_projection(augmented_images)
        logits = self.global_avg_pool(x)
        return logits
```

Next, implement a custom random crop layer and use it as follows instead of `layers.RandomCrop`.

```
class CustomRandomCrop(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, size, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = size
        
    def call(self, inputs, training=True):
        if training:
            outputs = tf.map_fn(lambda img: tf.image.random_crop(img,
                                               self.size), inputs)
        else:
            outputs = tf.image.resize(inputs, self.size[:-1])
        return outputs
            
    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update(
            {
                'size': self.size,
            }
        )
        return config
```

```
def get_augmentation_model():
    """Build the data augmentation model."""
    data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Resizing(...),
            CustomRandomCrop(...), # custom random crop
            layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
            layers.Rescaling(1 / 255.0),
        ]
    )
    return data_augmentation
```

After these changes, we can now do as follows without any error.

```
x,y = next(iter(train_ds))
print(x.shape, y.shape)
model(x.shape) 
# OK

history = model.fit(
    x=x, y=y,
    epochs=1
) 
# OK

model.evaluate(x, y)
# OK
```

Saving and reloading work as well.

```
model.save('/content/VIT-SHIFT')
# OK

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/VIT-SHIFT')
# OK

np.testing.assert_allclose(
    model.predict(x), new_model.predict(x)
)
# OK
```

HERE is the complete working [Code-in-Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lUgzDUj6AtUrTAy1VX1kmhq0mSCyM4PW?usp=sharing). Please save the file, I might erase the file from the drive someday.

Lastly, FYI, `history.save('...')`, you can't do that in keras. In order to save the `tensorflow/keras` model, please refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) document. The `history` object will return only the tracked metrics and loss during training time. For example

```
history = model.fit(
    x=x, y=y,
    epochs=1
)

history.history

{'accuracy': [0.09765625],
 'loss': [6.204378128051758],
 'top-5-accuracy': [0.36328125]}
```

You can save the training logs from the above dictionary or better use the [`CSVLogger`](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/csv_logger/) during training.