# Want to predict model output with some dummy inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am running a Keras model where I want to produce model output before compilation with some dummy input before compiling and training the model. Here I share some code of my model which I think is important to understand my model,
For complete code please visit [to this colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/106GsgIh4bXwQKDT0jtjsvvYzUcr0BOg4?usp=sharing) and you can also view the official [keras code here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/shiftvit/).

```
class ShiftViTModel(keras.Model):
"""The ShiftViT Model.

Args:
    data_augmentation (keras.Model): A data augmentation model.
    projected_dim (int): The dimension to which the patches of the image are
        projected.
    patch_size (int): The patch size of the images.
    num_shift_blocks_per_stages (list[int]): A list of all the number of shit
        blocks per stage.
    epsilon (float): The epsilon constant.
    mlp_dropout_rate (float): The dropout rate used in the MLP block.
    stochastic_depth_rate (float): The maximum drop rate probability.
    num_div (int): The number of divisions of the channesl of the feature
        map. Defaults to 12.
    shift_pixel (int): The number of pixel to shift. Default to 1.
    mlp_expand_ratio (int): The ratio with which the initial mlp dense layer
        is expanded to. Defaults to 2.
"""

def __init__(
    self,
    data_augmentation,
    projected_dim,
    patch_size,
    num_shift_blocks_per_stages,
    epsilon,
    mlp_dropout_rate,
    stochastic_depth_rate,
    num_div=12,
    shift_pixel=1,
    mlp_expand_ratio=2,
    **kwargs,
):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.data_augmentation = data_augmentation
    self.patch_projection = layers.Conv2D(
        filters=projected_dim,
        kernel_size=patch_size,
        strides=patch_size,
        padding="same",
    )
    self.stages = list()
    for index, num_shift_blocks in enumerate(num_shift_blocks_per_stages):
        if index == len(num_shift_blocks_per_stages) - 1:
            # This is the last stage, do not use the patch merge here.
            is_merge = False
        else:
            is_merge = True
        # Build the stages.
        self.stages.append(
            StackedShiftBlocks(
                epsilon=epsilon,
                mlp_dropout_rate=mlp_dropout_rate,
                num_shift_blocks=num_shift_blocks,
                stochastic_depth_rate=stochastic_depth_rate,
                is_merge=is_merge,
                num_div=num_div,
                shift_pixel=shift_pixel,
                mlp_expand_ratio=mlp_expand_ratio,
            )
        )
    self.global_avg_pool = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()

def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config()
    config.update(
        {
            "data_augmentation": self.data_augmentation,
            "patch_projection": self.patch_projection,
            "stages": self.stages,
            "global_avg_pool": self.global_avg_pool,
        }
    )
    return config

def _calculate_loss(self, data, training=False):
    (images, labels) = data

    # Augment the images
    augmented_images = self.data_augmentation(images, training=training)

    # Create patches and project the pathces.
    projected_patches = self.patch_projection(augmented_images)

    # Pass through the stages
    x = projected_patches
    for stage in self.stages:
        x = stage(x, training=training)

    # Get the logits.
    logits = self.global_avg_pool(x)

    # Calculate the loss and return it.
    total_loss = self.compiled_loss(labels, logits)
    return total_loss, labels, logits

def train_step(self, inputs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        total_loss, labels, logits = self._calculate_loss(
            data=inputs, training=True
        )

    # Apply gradients.
    train_vars = [
        self.data_augmentation.trainable_variables,
        self.patch_projection.trainable_variables,
        self.global_avg_pool.trainable_variables,
    ]
    train_vars = train_vars + [stage.trainable_variables for stage in self.stages]

    # Optimize the gradients.
    grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, train_vars)
    trainable_variable_list = []
    for (grad, var) in zip(grads, train_vars):
        for g, v in zip(grad, var):
            trainable_variable_list.append((g, v))
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(trainable_variable_list)

    # Update the metrics
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(labels, logits)
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

def test_step(self, data):
    _, labels, logits = self._calculate_loss(data=data, training=False)

    # Update the metrics
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(labels, logits)
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

Second block

```
model = ShiftViTModel(
data_augmentation=get_augmentation_model(),
projected_dim=config.projected_dim,
patch_size=config.patch_size,
num_shift_blocks_per_stages=config.num_shift_blocks_per_stages,
epsilon=config.epsilon,
mlp_dropout_rate=config.mlp_dropout_rate,
stochastic_depth_rate=config.stochastic_depth_rate,
num_div=config.num_div,
shift_pixel=config.shift_pixel,
mlp_expand_ratio=config.mlp_expand_ratio, 
)
```

actually I am trying to produce output from the above model like this

```
dummy_inputs = tf.ones((2, 32, 32, 3))
outputs = model(dummy_inputs, training=False)
print(outputs.shape)
```

but it generates an error that

> Unimplemented `tf.keras.Model.call()`: if you intend to create a
> `Model` with the Functional API, please provide `inputs` and `outputs`
> arguments. Otherwise, subclass `Model` with an overridden `call()`
> method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` method is not implemented and is required in [such implementation](https://keras.io/examples/vision/shiftvit/) if we need to inspect the model with dummy data. You can implement the `call` method in the `ShiftViTModel` class as follows with the used layers (see the `train_step` method).

```
def call(self, images):
   augmented_images = self.data_augmentation(images)
   x = self.patch_projection(augmented_images)
   logits = self.global_avg_pool(x)
   return logits
```

Now, if we do

```
model = ShiftViTModel( ... )
x,y = next(iter(train_ds))
print(x.shape, y.shape)
model(x).shape

(256, 32, 32, 3) (256, 1)
TensorShape([256, 96])
```

Comment: Thank You for your helpful  answer. I want to save this model after training but  I am unable to save when I do like this `model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/VIT-SHIFT') ` it says model is not defined. I have asked this question on stackoverflow [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480669/cant-save-a-keras-model-after-training?noredirect=1#comment128041348_72480669) but did not get any helpful answer.

Comment: And one thing which I want to ask about a list in`super().__init__` function named `self.stages = list()`. This is the most important part of this model and defining it in call function is also important. which you have skipped in above call function.

Comment: I have tried it to define it like
`def call(self, images):
   augmented_images = self.data_augmentation(images)
   x = self.patch_projection(augmented_images)
   y = self.stages(x)
   logits = self.global_avg_pool(y)
   return logits`
but it generates an error

Comment: Please see the answer to your another relevant question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72496860/9215780